# Odd Jbuilder Response - RubyOnRails - Jbuilder Gem - JSON Response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

```
class LineItem
  def stock_status
    8, true
  end
end
```

Template

```
json.stock, json.required_stock = line_item.stock_status
```

Response

```
stock=: 6,
required_stock=: true
```

Want the response to be

```
stock: 6,
required_stock: true
```

Comment: How does the stock_status method look like

Comment: Can you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class LineItem
  def stock_status
    [8, true]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try update template to

```
json.(line_item.stock_status, :stock, :required_stock)
```